C - Packed struct - different behavior in different compilers
** EDIT **
(original message below)
When using mingw64-gcc  (instead of common mingw), looks like the result is correct.
I run the 'gcc -v' option, on the various gcc version. Maybe someone may understand the differences?
mingw compiler (erroneous output)
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
ming64 compiler
COLLECT_GCC=C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-12.2.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64 --enable-host-shared --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-win32-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib ' LD_FOR_TARGET=/c/mingw-builds/msvcrt-seh-win32/x86_64-1220-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v10-rev2/mingw64/bin/ld.exe --with-boot-ldflags=' -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
Thread model: win32
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12.2.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
Linux cross compiler
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --with-headers --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --enable-libatomic --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-dependency-tracking SED=/bin/sed
Thread model: win32
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10-win32 20220113 (GCC)
I found another compile, from mingw64, which results correctly:
** ORIGINAL MESSAGE **
I've wrote a function that writes file-info into another file (in bin-format).
I've built it for WINDOWS executable, in two different environments:
eclipse, using mingw gcc:

GCC: (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

linux, using cross-compiler (x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32):

GCC: (GNU) 10-win32 20220113

The file info is a packed struct, sized 128bytes, as follows:
#define STR_SIZE            32
typedef char string_t[STR_SIZE];

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t    a   : 15;
        uint32_t    b   : 1;
        uint32_t    c   : 8;
        uint32_t    d   : 8;
    } __attribute__((packed)) fields;
    uint32_t raw;
} general_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     hour;
    uint8_t     minutes;
    uint8_t     day;
    uint8_t     month;
    uint16_t    year;
} __attribute__((packed)) full_date_t;

typedef struct
{
    general_t     general;
    uint32_t      size;
} __attribute__((packed)) info_t;

typedef struct 
{ /* starting from offset 4 */
    full_date_t    date;     /*  6 bytes - offset  4: 9 */
    string_t     my_str;    /* 32 bytes - offset 10:41 */
    info_t   v1;             /*  8 bytes - offset 42:49 */
    info_t   v2;             /*  8 bytes - offset 50:57 */
    info_t   v3;             /*  8 bytes - offset 58:65 */
    info_t   v4;             /*  8 bytes - offset 66:73 */
    info_t   v5;             /*  8 bytes - offset 74:81 */
    uint32_t crc;            /*  4 bytes - offset 82:85 */
} __attribute__((packed)) fields_t;

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t  crc1;
        fields_t  fields;
        uint8_t   reserved[TOTAL_SIZE - sizeof(fields_t) - sizeof(uint32_t)];
    } __attribute__((packed)) fields;
    uint8_t raw[TOTAL_SIZE];
} full_info_t;

After building the code, and running it to build the info-file, I get different results in the bin file (besides the date - I hardcoded it all to 0x12345678).
the last CRC field, inside the 'fields_t' type, is located differently:

on the left you can see the linux built result, and on the right the windows built result (both built for exe executable in windows).
The correct offset of the CRC, if the linux built executable, while the windows built adds 2 bytes of padding.
What can cause the difference?

Remember also that bitfields do not have a standardized packing. It’s implementation-defined.

Just guessing, but perhaps a "Windows" build tries to mimic Microsoft's compiler, which is known to allocate bitfields different than Linux compilers. If so, I wouldn't be surprised at all if a 6 byte field gets padded to 8 bytes.

@BoP - but it's not a 6 byte field.
it's a 4 bytes field that is not aligned to 4 bytes.
Yet, all other fields are as well, not aligned, and yet, the difference is only in the last field

Seems like a compiler error. I have not been able to reproduce. If possible, try a newer compiler version for Windows and/or try fiddling around with the definition, e.g. get rid of the unions, to find a minimal example of the issue and possibly a work-around.

@nielsen
I edited with some more info, maybe it gives a clue?

Probably not a problem here, but types ending with _t that are not reserved by the C standard such as uint32_t are reserved by POSIX.  And Linux is effectively a POSIX implementation.

And FWIW, you're already going cross-platform on Windows and Linux.  Bitfields and packed structures are playing with fire in the first place, and effectively can not be relied on at all when going cross-platform, even on the same hardware such as x86,  If this code is ever ported onto ARM-based systems, the odds are very high it won't work at all.

@AndrewHenle
I know it's not reserved, but it's a convention I use.
Can you explain more about the bitfields issue?
It's actually FW here, so the bitfield is relevant for registers access...
